# how to assign value to char * array[] in C++

Tags: c++

I want to assign string to char array

here is code -

```
char *resultArray[100];
int cnt = 0;
void MySAX2Handler::startElement(const XMLCh* const uri, const XMLCh* const localname,
                                 const XMLCh* const qname, const Attributes& attrs)
{
   char* message = XMLString::transcode(localname);
   resultArray[cnt] = message;
   cnt++;

   for (int idx = 0; idx < attrs.getLength(); idx++)
   {
      char* attrName = XMLString::transcode(attrs.getLocalName(idx));
      char* attrValue = XMLString::transcode(attrs.getValue(idx));
      resultArray[cnt] = attrName;
      cnt++;
      resultArray[cnt] = attrValue;
      cnt++;
   }
   XMLString::release(&message);
}
```

after iterating through resultArray, its printing some garbage values

Comment: please indicate where in the code your problem manifests it self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attrName` and `attrValue` are both pointers and `char` is a type of integer, so the assignment operator will simply copy the value of the pointer (the address), not the content.

Either loop through the strings or use some version of `strcpy()`, or indeed one of the C++ string libraries.

Answer (score 0):

First off, when you declare your array, you should use

```
char *resultArray = new ResultArray[100];
```

vs

```
char *resultArray[100];
```

Next, you shouldn't ever use a loop to fill up a bounded array without knowing the limits of the loop. You will overflow your array, and cause a segfault. Unless of course you know your length won't reach close to 100. (still a bad idea, but to slap something together quickly, I won't complain)

Without more information, I can't tell you why you're getting garbage. How are you printing these out? What do those 'transcode' functions do? Where is the data coming from?

PS - remember you can use

```
resultArray[cnt++] = attrName;
resultArray[cnt++] = attrValue;
```